# Problema al retornar una lista (entity framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hice este código y quiero que me retorne un objeto para luego, con el metodo LoadChampions, llamarlo desde mi capa de presentación a la de negocio y así llenar mi datagridview.

```
public List<Campeones> LoadChampions()

 {
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        var champions = (from p in NarachiCTX.Campeones 
        select p.Nombre).ToList();

        return champions;

    }

 }
```

El problema es que espera un List < Campeones> y devuelve de tipo string. Quiero hacer que el codigo me cargue en mi dgv esta columna: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59QpX.png

Comment: Agrega los detalles que sean necesarios para reproducir tu escenario. Gracias :D

Comment: Cuales detalles?

Comment: Tu método es de tipo `List<Campeones>` y en linq estas haciendo `select p.Nombre`, que asumo, es un `string`, para solucionarlo simplemente hace `select p`, de todos modos, en tu caso, creo que usar Method Syntax es mucho más sencillo.. `var champions = NarachiCTX.Campeones.ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendiendo que la clase `Campeones` es la misma que estas mpeando en `entity framework` solo la retornas directo

```
public List<Campeones> LoadChampions()
{
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        return NarachiCTX.Campeones.ToList();
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, no recomiendo que retornes como respuestas a la view la misma entidad que mapeas, mas que nada porque puede haber problemas si hay entidades relacionadas, por eso se deberia crear una clase para el modelo de la view utilice

```
public class CompeonModel{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    //otras propiedades
}
```

entonces utilizas

```
public List<CampeonModel> LoadChampions()
{
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        var champions = from p in NarachiCTX.Campeones 
                        select new CampeonModel()
                        {
                            Nombre = p.Nombre,
                            //otras propiedades
                        };

        return champions.ToList();
    }
}
```

de esta forma separas la persistencia de los datos que recibe la view, pudiendo controlar lo que visualizas

Comment: Lo que hice fue crear una clase (Campeones) donde contiene 2 propiedades (ID, Nombre). Si uso:

public List<Campeones> LoadChampions()
{
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        return NarachiCTX.Campeones.ToList();
    }
}

Me devuelve en mi DGV todas las columnas. Yo solo quiero que se visualice la columna Nombre.